# Update field on Salesforce based on field edited in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, field-update

I want to update custom field on custom object in Salesforce record.I am not able to update field. 
[image]

So basically I want is when value changes from picklist , value should be updated in respective record of salesforce as well.

Comment: Are you using <apex:inputField> tag to display picklist field? Is there only one record displayed or list of records displayed?

Comment: @user36778 Yes I uses <apex:inputField> tag to display field. There is list of records to display.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Onchange" attribute of the  tag (I assume you are using apex:inputfield tag).

Basically, you can create an apex method in your apex controller to update the field value. Also, create an action function on VF page. This action function will call Apex Method that you created.

Now, in "Onchange" event of the picklist field, call this action function. So, called action function will make a call to Apex Method and this apex method will make a DML statement to  save picklist value.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer in detail? Specially on "action function on VF page"...

Comment: The Visualforce Developer Guide has [details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) on the `<apex:actionFunction>` component.